# I don't understand ptr_fun

Tags: c++, string, stl

I ran into this ptr_fun thing in one of the c++ code, I tried reading up on it from cplusplus.com, but I honestly can't figure out what this function pointer is suppose to do.

The code of interest is very simple, trims the empty parts off the beginning of a string.

```
static inline string & trim_beg(string & s) {
  s.erase(s.begin(), find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), not1(ptr_fun < int, int > (isspace))));
  return s;
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ptr_fun

Comment: You shouldn't have to specify template arguments, `ptr_fun(::isspace)` should do. `ptr_fun`'s only purpose is to wrap `isspace` and provide the member `typedef` `argument_type` which is required by [`unary_negate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/unary_negate) (the thing that `not1` returns). So the `find_if` call is going to return an iterator to the first element for which `!isspace` is true.

Answer (score 2):

From Effective STL (Item 40) by Scott Meyers:

> The only thing ptr_fun does is make some typedefs available. That's
>   it. These typedefs are required by not1, and that's why applying not1
>   to ptr_fun but applying not1 to ... directly doesn't work. 
>   ... lacks the typedefs that not1 demands.

This is basically the same answer given by Praetorian in comments above but Effective STL provides a more general explanation.